# How does AWS Athena manage to execute queries immediately?

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

Does Athena have a gigantic cluster of machines ready to take queries from users and run them against their data? Are they using a specific open-source cluster management software for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe AWS will never disclose how they operate Athena service. However, as Athena is managed PrestoDB the overall design can be deduced based on that.

PrestoDB does not require cluster manager like YARN, Messos. It has own planner and scheduler that is able to run SQL physical plan on worker nodes.

I assume that AWS within each availability zone maintains PrestoDB coordinator connected to data catalog(AWS Glue) and set of presto worker. Workers are elastic and autoscaled. In case of inactivity, they're downscaled, but when the burst of activity occurs new workers added to the cluster.

Comment: Do you think there is only one coordinator per AZ or would you say there are a number of coordinators per AZ, increasing with load. Basically I'm wondering whether a coordinator can be a bottleneck?

Comment: @SunilKumbhar good question. I believe it's multiple coordinators per AZ. As it's physically impossible to serve all request given AWS scale. Usually, the coordinator is not bottlenecked as it does only SQL parsing and planning. The heavy lifting work is done by the workers. But for fault tolerance reason you need to maintain multiple coordinators and reroute traffic between them.